# No render image in QML from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I try display image in QML from C++ code.
In start I create `QImage` from raw data:

```
const QImage image(frame->buffer, frame->width, frame->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

Then send to QML.

C++ part:

```
...
m_image = image;
emit newImage();
...
```

And:

```
QString ImageRender::getFrame() const
{
    QByteArray bArray;
    QBuffer buffer(&bArray);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    m_image.save(&buffer, "JPEG");

    QString imagePath("data:image/jpg;base64,");
    imagePath.append(QString::fromLatin1(bArray.toBase64().data()));

    return imagePath;
}
```

QML part:

```
Connections {
    target: imageRender
    
    onNewImage: {
      imageArea.source = imageRender.getFrame()
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id: imageScreen
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "#000000"

    ColumnLayout {
       id: column

       anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
       anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
       width: parent.width * 0.9
       height: parent.height * 0.9

       Rectangle {
           width: 352; height: 640
           anchors.centerIn: parent
           Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter

           Image {
               id: imageArea
               anchors.fill: parent
               source: ""
               fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            }
       }
    }
}
```

I have gray rectangle only.

Comment: It looks like your getFrame() function is actually returning the entire data of the image as a QString. I don't think that will work. I recommend using [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickimageprovider.html).

Comment: Showing an image like this should work. Try to debug the problem: is the slot called? what string does `getFrame` return? does it work if you manually assign this string to [`Image.source`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-image.html#source-prop), e.g. `source: "data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYA...`? And finally, make sure the image you're passing to QML is valid, i.e. it's not a "gray rectangle".

Comment: @absolute.madness, I checked - slot called. And when i do ```m_image.save("out.jpeg");``` I get image.

Comment: @ZeusBios I used the code similar to yours (some of your code I didn't even modify), a sample image and Qt 6. I came to the conclusion that I can't reproduce the problem and that we need more details (e.g. in the form of [mre]),

Comment: Problem was in speed send data. If scale image to small size, that image  rendered. But quality very bad

Comment: @ZeusBios I couldn't reproduce the problem even with larger images, but I didn't test much. If it stops working from certain dimensions this might be a sign of a Qt bug, but again you'll need the [mre] to report it. And of course you always have an alternative with `QQuickImageProvider` as it was suggested in the first comment.

Comment: And if it's for a video don't use `QQuickImageProvider` either, use `VideoOutput` and a custom source object presenting `QVideoFrame` on its assigned surface.

Comment: I have used the "data:" URI to do videos before, but, there has always been an issue in timing. Since, the Image renders the component asynchronously, it actually takes time for it to convert the base64 to binary then to unpack the binary to an image to render. By which time, a new video frame may have arrived. So, basically the Image component can never keep up with your frames. Whereas a solution based on QQuickImageProvider would mean that your actual QImage gets rendered. It's worth trying to migrate away from the base64 approach.